# Auth::user() is not working for Guard authentication in laravel 5.6

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.6

i made multiple authentication for two user tables **(users, admins)**. For **users** table i used the laravel default **LoginController** while for **admins** i made **AdminLoginController**. I also made **admin** guard for admins.

```
     'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

The login is working perfectly. i can redirect to adminHome for admins and userHome for users after successful login. Now for the admins, i want to get the authenticated user using the following statement, it prints null.

```
   var_dump(Auth::user());
```

But when i try the following, it works.

```
  var_dump(auth()->guard('admin')->user());
```

How i cant get the authenticated user when admins are logged in, using Auth::user()?

Comment: Have you tried `auth('admin')->user();`? Because your admin class is another guard.

Comment: yes, its working. thanks, but is there any way to enable the Auth::user() to get the authenticated user?

Comment: You can create a custom helper function which will check for both guards, or change the default guard to admin in `config/auth.php`.

Comment: Now i understand, thanks for you time @Chin Leung.

Comment: Np! Have a nice day. :)